# TextBox sizing inside ScrollView with horizontal scroll

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with the `TextBox` control.
Be aware of the `ScrollViewer` as this makes the difference.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="20"
                 Text = "A short text">
        </TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

It results in this:

[image: Result with short text]

It looks like expected and it expends/shrinks nicely if the window is resized.
So far so good, but what happens if the text is a bit longer?

This happens:

[image: Result with longer text]

The `TextBox` now grows to fit the text inside which is 
a) because there is a `ScrollView` that allows horizontal scrolling and
b) results in a really ugly UI (as the right margin isn't visible, but a scrollbar is, etc..)

Does anybody know how I could achieve the look from the first screenshot even with the longer text (while keeping the ScrollViewer)?

I thought about setting a maximum width for the `TextBox` but it prevented the `TextBox` from growing with the window which isn't acceptable.

Comment: What's the reason for using a `ScrollViewer` if you don't want your content to scroll?

Comment: try binding TextBox.Width to ScrollViewer.ActualWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may confused the `Width` or `ActualWidth` of `ScrollViewer` with its `ScrollableWidth`, if you don't limit the width of `TextBox`, the `ScrollableWidth` will grow up with the width of `TextBox`. Limit the width of the `TextBox` won't solve your problem.

> ...the right margin isn't visible, but a scrollbar is..

I guess what you need is something like this:

[image]

xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="20" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" 
              HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" Height="45">
    <TextBox x:Name="tb"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             BorderThickness="0"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can customize the `ScrollViewer` to make it behavior like a `TextBox`, for example when got focus, the `Border` will be shown or something others.

Comment: I think this is a pretty nice idea

Answer (score 1):

Change the `MaxWidth` property of the `TextBox` as you resize the window would solve your problem. Although, I don't think it's a clean way to do that.

```
    int margin = 40; // Set your margin

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InputTextBox.MaxWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width - margin;
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var size = e.Size;
        InputTextBox.MaxWidth = size.Width - margin;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Padding property on your scrollviewer instead of Margin, try this

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">">
        <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="20,0">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Margin="20"
             Text = "A short text">
            </TextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```